# How does Qiskit Primitives Estimator compute expectation values?

Tags: measurement, qiskit

The Qiskit Primitives [`Estimator`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.primitives.Estimator.html) class is implemented to work in two different ways depending on the `shots` parameter nature:

> shots (None or int) – The number of shots. If None, it calculates the
> exact expectation values. Otherwise, it samples from normal
> distributions with standard errors as standard deviations using normal
> distribution approximation.

I guess that, with an integer number of shots, the quantum circuit execution is repeated many times and each measurement is collected in order to get the final result as the measurements average value.
But how does `Estimator` calculate *exact expectation values* when `shots=None`?

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look to the [`qiskit.primitives.estimator.Estimator`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/primitives/estimator.html#Estimator) source code, you can figure out that, when `shots=None`, the expectation value $\langle O \rangle = \langle \psi | O | \psi \rangle$ is computed by something like:

```
final_state = Statevector(circ)
expectation_value = final_state.expectation_value(obs)
```

where `circ` is the `QuantumCircuit` preparing your state $\psi$ and `obs` is your operator $O$. This means that $\langle O \rangle$ is computed exactly by performing all the linear algebra calculations implemented in the method [`Statevector.expectation_value`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/quantum_info/states/statevector.html#Statevector.expectation_value).

More interestingly, when an integer number of shots $N$ is passed, Qiskit does **not** run the simulation $N$ times to calculate the mean value of the measurement outcomes; instead, it calls the `numpy` random generator to sample from a normal distribution $\mathcal{N}_{\mu,\sigma}$:

```
expectation_value = numpy.random.default_rng().normal(μ, σ)
```

where $\mu = \langle O \rangle$ (computed exactly as in the previous case) and $\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{\langle O^2 \rangle - \langle O \rangle^2}{N}}$.

Comment: The primitives can be used to access the real hardware devices.  But 'Qiskit does not run the simulation N times' applies to simulations only, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you run your circuit on real hardware devices you can't even have access to the `Statevector` object of course. However, you can use Qiskit primitives on IBM simulators as well!

Answer (score 0):

By calculating:

$\langle \psi | O |\psi\rangle $

Where $O$ is the observable being measured and $| \psi\rangle$ is the state before measurement.